# \lowercase with \IfSubStr and \StrDel

Tags: expansion, capitalization, xstring

I'm trying convert an argument to lowercase, strip out the spaces, and then search for the resulting string in a list. Thus far, I've had no luck.

Here's the code I would instinctively expect to work:

```
\newcommand{\mylist}{one,two,three}

\newcommand{\checkInList}[1]{ 
\StrDel{#1}{ }[\temp]
\IfSubStr{\mylist}{\lowercase{\temp}}
{yes}
{no}
}

\checkinlist{one}
```

I would expect that to print `yes`, but it does not.

I've found numerous questions also dealing with this topic, but so far none of the solutions have worked for me. The closest I came to a solution was in [\uppercase does not work with \IfSubStr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94221/uppercase-does-not-work-with-ifsubstr), but trying to alter that solution to my code just resulted in both `yes` and `no` being printed. I also made some slight progress with [Pass a macro (with arguments) as an argument for another macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/pass-a-macro-with-arguments-as-an-argument-for-another-macro), but ultimately failed in the end there as well.

If there's a better way to strip spaces, force case, and check in a list of things, I am entirely open to something completely different. I have no real reason to stick with any of the commands I'm currently using over any others.

Comment: Are you open to `expl3` features?

Comment: `\lowercase` is not expandable. You should lowercase the string in advance, then do the search.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't know anything about `expl3` to know why I'd be opposed, so I suppose not

Comment: @SnoringFrog: It's the 'new' LaTeX 'programming syntax -- quite powerful ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primitive `\lowercase` is not expandable; you have to first lowercase the argument and then use the lowercased string:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mylist}{one,two,three}

\newcommand{\checkinlist}[1]{%
  \lowercase{\def\temp{#1}}%
  \StrDel{\temp}{ }[\temp]%
  \IfSubStr{\mylist}{\temp}{yes}{no}%
}

\begin{document}

\checkinlist{one}

\checkinlist{One}

\checkinlist{o N e}

\checkinlist{o N f}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried something like this at one point, but was using `\def\temp{\lowercase{#1}}`. Putting `lowercase` on the outside never occurred to me.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an `expl3` version

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\mylist}{one,two,three, egreg was faster}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\CheckInList}[2]{%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\text_lowercase:n {#1}} %transform the list lowercase
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {\l_tmpa_tl} % make a real list
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl {\text_lowercase:n {#2}} % lower case second arg
  \clist_if_in:NVTF \l_tmpa_clist {\l_tmpb_tl} {Yes!} {No!} % Check if #2 is in the list
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\CheckInList{\mylist}{One}

\CheckInList{\mylist}{two}

\CheckInList{\mylist}{Egreg was faster}

\CheckInList{\mylist}{Should egreg get the tick?}

\end{document}
```

[image]