# Implementing a keyword / token / tag system

Tags: expl3, xparse, arrayjob

I want to have a keyword / tag / label / token system for my documents. There will be a hard coded list of allowed keywords and all theorems/examples/exercises will (optionally) be tagged with one of those keywords. Compiling the document should check whether a valid keyword is used as tag and (if required) print it.

I am trying to implement using the `arrayjob` package. All my tags will be stored in a array called `tagtoken` and a command `\tagit` will do the job of actual tagging. I tried to hack the code with bits and pieces cargo-cult-lifted from various questions of tex.stackexchange. However I have no real knowledge of `expl3`.

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob,expl3,xparse,pgffor}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newarray\tagtoken
\readarray{tagtoken}{RAG&TAG&BAG} % should be case insensitive
\newarray\tokenlist

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tagit}{m}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\tl_lower_case:n{#1}}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {,} {&} \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {\s+} {} \l_tmpa_tl
    \readarray{tokenlist}{\l_tmpa_tl} % does not work
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {&} {, } \l_tmpa_tl % just for displaying
    \newline Keywords = \tl_use:N \tl_upper_case:n{\l_tmpa_tl}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}
        Dummy theorem \tagit{g,h , k, rag, TAG} % should throw an error and stop compilation till invalid tokens are purged.
    \end{theorem}

    %\foreach\x in {1,...,3} {\noindent tagtoken(\x) = \tagtoken(\x)\hfil\\}
    one = \tokenlist(1) % no output

    \begin{theorem}
        two \tagit{rag,TaG} % no error
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        three \tagit{rag, RAg} % should produce a warning for repeated tags
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

How do I make it work? Sorry for asking a cargo-cult question.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you want to do. Am I right in thinking that the `\tagit` command should check if the tags are valid, check for duplicates and then print a list of keys a the end of the environment. Is that right? If this is all that you want then this is easy to do with LaTeX3 sequences -- and I don't understand the use/need for the regular expressions in the definition of the `\tagit` macro.

Comment: Why are you mixing expl3 with an rather old package like arrayjob? Why don't you use the expl3 data structures instead?

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in using `arrayjob`, as `expl3` provides better functions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definetags}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_magguu_tags_clist { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\tagit}{m}
 {
  \magguu_tags_tagit:n { #1 }
 }

%% variables
\clist_new:N \g_magguu_tags_clist
\seq_new:N \l__magguu_tags_seq

%% variants
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \clist_if_in:Nn { Nx } { T,F,TF }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \seq_if_in:Nn { Nx } { T,F,TF }

%% messages
\msg_new:nnnn { magguu/tags } { invalid }
 {
  Invalid~tag~'#1'~on~line~\msg_line_number:
 }
 {
  The~tag~'#1'~is~not~among~the~valid~tags. \\ Fix~it.
 }
\msg_new:nnn { magguu/tags } { duplicate }
 {
  The~tag~'#1'~is~duplicate~on~line~\msg_line_number:
 }

%% functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \magguu_tags_tagit:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__magguu_tags_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:NxTF \g_magguu_tags_clist { \tl_upper_case:n { ##1 } }
     { % the tag is valid
      \seq_if_in:NxTF \l__magguu_tags_seq { \tl_upper_case:n { ##1 } }
       { % the tag is duplicate
        \msg_warning:nnn { magguu/tags } { duplicate } { ##1 }
       }
       { % add the tag
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l__magguu_tags_seq { \tl_upper_case:n { ##1 } }
       }
     }
     { % invalid tag
      \msg_error:nnn { magguu/tags }{ invalid } { ##1 }
     }
   }
   \newline Keywords:\nobreakspace\seq_use:Nn \l__magguu_tags_seq { ,~ }
 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\definetags{RAG,TAG,BAG}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Dummy theorem \tagit{g,h , k, rag, TAG}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
two \tagit{rag,TaG} % no error
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
three \tagit{rag, RAg} % should produce a warning for repeated tags
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Console output (errors and warnings)

```latex
! Package magguu/tags Error: Invalid tag 'g' on line 69

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.69 Dummy theorem \tagit{g,h , k, rag, TAG}

? h

The tag 'g' is not among the valid tags.
Fix it.

? 

! Package magguu/tags Error: Invalid tag 'h' on line 69

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.69 Dummy theorem \tagit{g,h , k, rag, TAG}

? 

! Package magguu/tags Error: Invalid tag 'k' on line 69

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.69 Dummy theorem \tagit{g,h , k, rag, TAG}

? 

Package magguu/tags Warning: The tag 'RAg' is duplicate on line 77
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with list processing from the `etoolbox` package. The idea is to create a list with allowed tags, and then check each item from the input of `\tagit` against this list.

A separate list with already used tags (which is reset for each new tag list) can be used to check for duplicates.

The errors and warnings can be created with the built-in `\GenericError` and `\GenericWarning` commands.

Case-insensitive checking can be achieved by creating the allowed tag list in lower case and converting the tags to lower case before checking against the list. This requires a bit of strange syntax, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286386/.

In the code below the duplicate check is performed first, and the error checking and actual tag printing are done only if the tag is not a duplicate.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
% create list of allowed tags
\forcsvlist{\listadd\allowedtags}{rag,tag,bag}
% macro for processing a single tag
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
% put argument in lower case
\lowercase{\def\lcarg{#1}}%
% check if item is already used
\xifinlist{\lcarg}{\useditems}{\GenericWarning{xxx}{Warning: duplicated tag '#1'}}{%
% check if item is in list of allowed tags
\xifinlist{\lcarg}{\allowedtags}{\fbox{\normalfont #1} }{\GenericError{xxx}{tag not allowed: #1}{please remove tag}{further help}}}%
% add item to list of used items
\listeadd{\useditems}{\lcarg}%
}
% command for processing tag list
\newcommand{\tagit}[1]{%
% reset list of used items
\gdef\useditems{}
% execute \do for each item in the list
\docsvlist{#1}%
}

\begin{theorem}
Dummy theorem \tagit{g,h , k, rag, TAG, rag} % should throw an error and stop compilation till invalid tokens are purged.
%Dummy theorem \tagit{rag, TAG, RaG}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This triggers the error:

```
! tag not allowed: g.

please remove tag
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18 Dummy theorem \tagit{g,h , k, rag, TAG, rag}
                                                  % should throw an error an...
```

Commenting the offending line and uncommenting the next triggers the warning:

```
Warning: duplicated tag 'RaG' on input line 19.
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]

Of course if you want to do something different with the tags (conditional printing, making a list/index somewhere else in the document, etc) then you should modify the first clause of the allowed tags check (the `\fbox` part).