# Use a command with variables that uses \IfSubStr on the lowercased value of the input variables

Tags: pandoc, xstring, renewcommand, textcase

**[Similar questions]**
I looked at [\lowercase with \IfSubStr and \StrDel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286383/lowercase-with-ifsubstr-and-strdel) but the suggestions didn't work. I apparently may have expl3 since I can use \newcommand.

**[Issue]**
I want to pass a variable to a command, have it expand the variable, lowercase the value, do \IfSubStr, and create a new command if the lowercased value matches. The problem is that I can find no way to get the variable value lowercased for the \IfSubStr.

**[Tools]**

FMPP version 0.9.16, build 2018-09-03T21:47:30Z
Currently using FreeMarker version 2.3.28

pandoc 2.7.3
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.2, skylighting 0.8.1
Copyright (C) 2006-2019 John MacFarlane

**[Build]**

Execute the following in pdfTex

**[Source]**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}

\def\abcVariable{abc}
\def\DEFVariable{DEF}
\def\refVariable{nothing}
\def\dbgstr{debug}

\newcommand{\setCmd}[3]{%
    \lowercase{\def\tmpa{#1}}%
    \lowercase{\edef\tmpb{#2}}%
    \IfSubStr{\tmpa}{\tmpb}
    {\renewcommand{#3}{#2}}{%
        \edef\dbgstr{inputs: #1, #2; lowercased: \tmpa, \tmpb}%
    }
}

\newcommand{\setVariable}[1]{%
    \setCmd{#1}{\abcVariable}{\refVariable}%
    \setCmd{#1}{\DEFVariable}{\refVariable}%
}

\setVariable{thishasdefinthemiddle}

\refVariable

\dbgstr
\end{document}
```

**[Response]**

nothing
inputs: thishasadefinthemiddle, DEF; lowercased: thishasadefinthemiddle, DEF

**[Expected]**

DEF
inputs: thishasadefinthemiddle, DEF; lowercased: thishasadefinthemiddle, def

**[Debugging 1]**

The use of `\setCmd{#1}{\abcVariable}{\refVariable}%` works, but not for the right reasons.
Then I consider `\setCmd{#1}{\DEFVariable}{\refVariable}%`.
I think `\lowercase{\def\tmpa{#1}}%` expanded to `\lowercase{\def\tmpa{abcdef}}%` and then assigned `\tmpa` with `abcdef`. Great.
I think `\lowercase{\edef\tmpb{#2}}%` expanded to `\lowercase{\edef\tmpb{\DEFVariable}}%` and then

1. lowercased to `\edef\tmpb{\DEFVariable}}%` because `\lowercase` doesn't lowercase csnames, or
2. lowercased to `\edef\tmpb{\defvariable}}%` and then should have complained that `\defvariable` does not exist, or
3. lowercased and expanded `\defvariable` anyway to `DEF`, or
4. just stopped expanding for some reason.

Then `\IfSubStr{\tmpa}{\tmpb}` expanded to `\IfSubStr{abcdef}{\DEFVariable}` which expanded to `\IfSubStr{abcdef}{DEF}`, which ran the {false} path.
I need `\DEFVariable` to fully expand to `DEF` and then get lowercased for the `\IfSubStr`.

**[Debugging 2]**

Then I tried making a command to do the lowercasing:

```
\newcommand{\mylwr}[1]{%
    \edef\x{%
        \noexpand\edef\noexpand\tmpb{\text_lowercase:n #1}}%
    \x}
```

and replaced `\lowercase{\edef\tmpb{#2}}%` with `\mylwr{#2}`, but got a `Missing $ inserted / 1.88 dbgstr: \dbgstr`, so I probably don't have the package with `\text_lowercase:n`. But using `\lowercase` gives an output of:

```
setVariable:
refVariable: nothing
dbgstr: inputs: abcdef, DEF; lowercased: abcdef, def
```

Looks great, until you realize the \IfSubStr failed and it was only when the output was written that the full expansion produced the lowercase `def`.

**[Debugging 3]**

Then I tried creating a substitute for the `\IfSubStr` command:

```
\newcommand{\IfSubStrIC}[2]{%
    \lowercase{\edef\x{\noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{\expanded{#2}}}}%
    \x}
```

The output was back to:

```
setVariable:
refVariable: abc
dbgstr: inputs: abcdef, DEF; lowercased: abcdef, DEF
```

**[Debugging 4]**

I tried various `\expanded` and `\expandafter` and `\expandafter\expandafter` to try to get the variable expanded to lowercase it, but nothing worked.

Does anyone know how to get a value from a variable and lowercase it for `\IfSubStr`, or some way to do something equivalent?

Comment: I'm trying to add a complete test file, but my comment is limited to 600 characters.

Comment: `Does anyone know how to get a value from a variable and lowercase `  I assume you mean `\def\zzz{ABC}  \lowercase\expandafter{\zzz}`  which returns `abc` but I have no idea how that fits the rest of your question

Comment: {Removed test file that had no spacing, HA} {But I don't have the reputation to edit my Post, apparently}

Comment: Found the tiny little Edit hyperlink while looking for a big red button with Edit in it. {Sorry}

Comment: the site design has its quirks:-)

Comment: Trying `\edef\tmpb{\lowercase\expandafter{#2}}%` produced output "nothing" but did lowercase \tmpb in \dbgstr. I just need it lowercased in the \IfSubStr

Comment: `\lowercase` isn't expandable so you do not want it inside the edef. (you would find this easier using expl3) but  `\def\zzz{ABC} 
\lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\zzzb\expandafter{\zzz}}` defines `\zzzb` to be the lowercase of `\zzz`

Comment: please don;t change the title  to SOLVED (otherwise we'd have tens of thousands of titles all starting that way)

Comment: @David-Carlisle, oops, thanks!. I'll just check the Accepted solution. I'll have to figure out if there is a way to thank commenters posts individually.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that the macros are expanded before `\lowercase` processes the token list.

Let's say you have `\def\foo{baz}`. If you do

```
\lowercase{\edef\tmpa{\foo}}
```

you get exactly the same as `\edef\tmpa{\foo}`, because `\lowercase` only changes *character tokens*. You might do

```
\lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\tmpa\expandafter{\foo}}
```

so that `\foo` is expanded prior to `\lowercase` starting its job. But this wouldn't work if instead of just `\foo` you have something more complex that expands to character tokens, say two macros, for instance.

To overcome the issue you can use `\expanded`, if you're sure that a fairly recent version of pdftex (or other engine) is used.

```
\newcommand{\setCmd}[3]{%
  \expanded{\lowercase{\def\noexpand\tmpa{#1}}}%
  \expanded{\lowercase{\def\noexpand\tmpb{#2}}}%
  \IfSubStr{\tmpa}{\tmpb}
    {\renewcommand{#3}{#2}}% true
    {\edef\dbgstr{inputs: #1, #2; lowercased: \tmpa, \tmpb}}% false
}
```

Otherwise, the usual trick:

```
\newcommand{\setCmd}[3]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \lowercase{\def\noexpand\tmpa{#1}}%
  }\x
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \lowercase{\def\noexpand\tmpb{#2}}%
  }\x
  \IfSubStr{\tmpa}{\tmpb}
    {\renewcommand{#3}{#2}}% true
    {\edef\dbgstr{inputs: #1, #2; lowercased: \tmpa, \tmpb}}% false
}
```

Comment: This works! I was trying \expand* lots of places, but not the Right places. I still can't figure out how \lowercase{\edef\tmpb{#2}} didn't work, but \expanded{\lowercase{\def\noexpand\tmpb{#2}}} did. If #2 became \DEFVariable, then \lowercase should have made \defvariable and failed to find the variable.

Comment: @JayTurner `\lowercase` does no expansion: it simply passes the token list to the inner level, from which it is “regurgitated” after changing *character tokens* to their lowercase variant; hence `\lowercase{\edef\tmpa{\var}}` is the same as `\edef\tmpa{\var}`. With `\expanded` or the other trick, `\var` is expanded *before* `\lowercase` enters into action. I added some comments.

Comment: I was confused about "\lowercase is non-expandable" and was thinking it meant that \lowercase had to be the outermost \command so that it would execute at all. That if it was nested it wouldn't "expand". But this makes more sense. Nesting works, #2 expands to \DEFVariable, then \lowercase executes and lowercase text, but not \variables, then \expanded says to expand \variables, expect for the \noexpand ones, then it executes the result. Thanks!